# Capturing pattern in a DataFrame and counting its length

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
>>>df
    Str
0   .....(((((................((((.(...).))))(((((....))))).(((((((((...))))))).))))))).................
1   .(((((..(((....(((((((........)))))))..)))..))).)).((((((((((.((..(((....)))....)).)))))))))).......
2   ((((((.(((((.(((...))))))))))....(((.((((.((.(((....))).)).))))..)))))))(..((((...))))..)...........
3   (((((((.((....((.((.((((..((.......(((...))).((((((((...))))))))....))..)))).)).))....))..)))))))...
```

I want to capture the portion starting from first opening bracket to the last opening bracket. I tried the following code for that:

```
df["stem"] = df["Str"].str.findall('[(][(.)]+[)]')
df["stem"] = df["stem"].astype("str")
```

The code does capture the blocks but prints it inside an array starting and ending with square brackets:

> ['regexblock']

```
>>>df
        Str stem
0   .....(((((................((((.(...).))))(((((....))))).(((((((((...))))))).))))))).................    ['(((((................((((.(...).))))(((((....))))).(((((((((...))))))).)))))))']
1   .(((((..(((....(((((((........)))))))..)))..))).)).((((((((((.((..(((....)))....)).)))))))))).......    ['(((((..(((....(((((((........)))))))..)))..))).)).((((((((((.((..(((....)))....)).))))))))))']
2   ((((((.(((((.(((...))))))))))....(((.((((.((.(((....))).)).))))..)))))))(..((((...))))..)...........    ['((((((.(((((.(((...))))))))))....(((.((((.((.(((....))).)).))))..)))))))(..((((...))))..)']
3   (((((((.((....((.((.((((..((.......(((...))).((((((((...))))))))....))..)))).)).))....))..)))))))...    ['(((((((.((....((.((.((((..((.......(((...))).((((((((...))))))))....))..)))).)).))....))..)))))))']
```

I need to find the length of each block, but due to this addition of special characters I get 4 extra counts. Is there anyway to get rid of these characters while handling regex?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find nested bracketes?

Comment: yes but along with the dots inside it. I need to find the total length of the string.

Comment: for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(len(row["stem"])-4)
does the trick. But I'm asking for some other efficient solution cause I may need to use the block in future

Comment: `str.findall` returns a list. Use `df["Str"].str.extract('([(][(.)]+[)])')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This one should do it:

```
df['Str'].str.extract('(\(.*\))')
```

Comment: That works. Thank you